# cannot login to gmail with pine (on Amazon)

Tags: server, security, email, gmail, email-client

kinda silly, but since Amazon has a faster connection than I have at home, thought I'd try `alpine` to see the IMAP performance with Gmail.  This is on Ubuntu 16.04 server running on EC2.

I know that the password is correct.  I don't have MFA (Multi-Factor Auth) enabled, but checked all through Google's doc's on suspicious activity and checked that insecure apps were enabled.  No suspicious activity showed on the Google account page.

Outside of enabling MFA, how would I explicitly "allow" a specific IP address with Gmail?  Sort of off-topic, but it **is** on Ubuntu...

Works with `lynx` from the instance:

```
   Search Images Maps Play YouTube News Gmail Drive More »

Account Options

   hawat.thufir@gmail.com | Account | Settings | Help | Sign out

   [warning_exc.gif] You are out of storage space and will soon be unable to send or receive emails until you free up space or
   purchase additional storage.

   You are currently viewing Gmail in basic HTML.   Switch to standard view | Set basic HTML as default view

Gmail by Google


   ____________________________  Search Mail  Search the Web  Show search options
    Create a filter

   Compose Mail

Folders

Inbox (364)

   Starred  star
   Sent Mail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after about half an hour, I received:

> ‘Suspicious sign in prevented’ email
>
> If you’ve received a ‘suspicious sign in prevented’ email from Google,
>   it means we recently blocked an attempt to access your account because
>   we weren’t sure it was really you. To help protect your account, we
>   send you an email when we notice unusual sign-in activity, like an
>   attempt to sign in from a different location or device than normal.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6063333?hl=en

while browsing.  After enabling the login, `alpine` isn't much faster on EC2 than locally -- just doesn't load large folders quickly, I suppose.

Comment: Since you are using your local connection to access the EC2 why would you expect it to be faster? The bottleneck of your own local connection is still in place, no?

Comment: Assume I was physically in Antarctica, using satellites/etc, but have an SSH connection to Amazon.  Amazon will load up large IMAP folders faster than my connection in Antarctica.  Displaying the *list* of e-mails can be done over dial-up/string&can/etc.